# Rails 3.2.2 SQL Query Builder

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to avoid reinventing the wheel here. I'm looking for a GEM that will take an existing Model and allow a user to choose the Fields they want to display in a View along with Filter criteria for the chosen fields.  This input would then build a generic data grid with the results.  A similar question was asked in 2009 [SQL query builder in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846055/sql-query-builder-in-rails) and I'm wondering if anyone knows if anything has been created in the interim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try one of these:

https://github.com/lunich/table_for

https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid