# Difference between Squeel and Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, squeel

Can anyone explain the difference between the two very similar looking gems 'Arel' and 'Squeel' for a rails newbie.

https://github.com/rails/arel Vs https://github.com/ernie/squeel

I am looking forward to building a simple Query builder where user will be given certain UI blocks it can used to construct SQL queries. Which gem out of the two will be more appropriate and why?

Similar Question:
[SQL query builder in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846055/sql-query-builder-in-rails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case comparison is incorrect. Squeel is built on Arel and has own DSL for constructing queries. Nothing special.

I think this can be done with any of the gems.